# Query SQL for table Column name push into PHP Array 1 Column per Index

Tags: php, sql

This is the code I am using:

```
$columnQuery = "select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'file_system_profiles'";
$getColumns = sqlsrv_query($conn, $columnQuery);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getColumns)) {
    $tempColumns = ($row[0] . PHP_EOL);
    $selectColumns = preg_split('/\s+/', $tempColumns);
    echo $selectColumns[0];
}
```

The problem is that $getColumns does end up with my column names in it, but it is one long string with no delimiters between each column name.  That is why I tried to use PHP_EOL to separate them by spaces in $tempColumns.  If I echo $tempColumns I do see all my column names separate by spaces.  Then when I do my preg_split on spaces/tabs/new lines I thought I would end up with the $selectColumns array with 1 column name in each index.  Unfortunately when I echo $selectColumns[0] I still get one long string with no spaces.

I know it may be more work for anyone answering, but if you could give me a clue as to why my code didn't work in addition to any code you provide I would appreciate the deeper understanding.

Comment: What does this result in when you execute this query directly on the database?

Comment: A table with a single column that contains each column name for that table  in its own row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\s` regular expression matches newlines, so when you use `preg_split()` you're discarding the newline that you concatenated.

But none of this is necessary, just print each result on a different line, using `<br>` as the line break in HTML.

```
$columnQuery = "select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'file_system_profiles'";
$getColumns = sqlsrv_query($conn, $columnQuery);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getColumns)) {
        echo $row['COLUMN_NAME'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work for me but ultimately I don't want to just print to the screen, I want it in an array that I can use to manipulate the data through loops and such.

Comment: So push it into an array with `$array[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME']`, what's the problem?

Comment: I think you got confused looking at the output of your script, which made it look like it's one long string. It's no different from any other query, each name is in a different row of results.

Comment: I guess I did get confused looking at the output, everything is working as expected now, thank you.